# Google Spreadsheet, weird "Reference out of range"-error

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-docs

This is my formula:

```
=INDEX(ImportData("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL
&a="&MONTH(EDATE(N18, 3))-1&"
&b="&DAY(EDATE(N18,3))&"
&c="&YEAR(EDATE(N18,3))&"
&d="&MONTH(EDATE(N18, 3))-1&"
&e="&DAY(EDATE(N18,3))&"
&f="&YEAR(EDATE(N18,3))&"
&g=d&ignore=.csv"),2,5)
```

This results in a "Reference out of range"-error. However, if I change the following part in every row it occurs:

```
(N18,3)
```

Into this:

```
(N18,1)
...or...
(N18,2)
```

...it works fine. So anything above "2" results in this error and I cant figure out why. It works well if I use it outside of this formula, eg:

```
=YEAR(EDATE(N18, 3))
```

My N18 looks like this btw:

```
1/7/2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crap, its wasn't the function. I was trying to get the quote for a Sunday and it wasn't automatically adjusted to the closest business day.